# "background-clip:text" has weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, polyfills

I am using a page that is using the css of `-webkit-background-clip:text` with a polyfill to get it working in browsers that don't support this.

Obviously, some browsers use Webkit (Chrome, Opera & Safari) and some don't (Firefox, IE), and I want the page to display the same (give or take the background clip) however this isn't happening on Firefox. The polyfill I'm using works but translates the text very weirdly in Firefox. Strangely enough, IE works (though the polyfill doesn't).

This is Firefox:
[image]

This is a Webkit browser:
[image]

And finally this is IE:
[image]

The polyfill I'm using is https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill

I've tried contacting the guy who made it but can't get any reply out of him.

Basically, I have no idea why Firefox is translating the text at all. I want it to either act as Internet Explorer and just display the text as white, or correctly display it.

**How would I go about doing that?**

If you need a page to work off, there is too much for a jsfiddle, but a link to the page can be found [here](http://spedwards.cz.cc/mh/events/new/).

Comment: `background-clip` [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) from Firefox 4.0, why do you need a polyfill ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes but not `background-clip:text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polyfill creates a SVG for Firefox, but doesn't seem to do a very good job at it. Removing 
`overflow: hidden` from the SVG element (set in svg.css) will let all the generated SVG show.

Comment: Ahh the `overflow:hidden` was my problem. Strangely though, svg.css was not linked anywhere on my page nor was it in the polyfill.